# How to detect distribution changes within population?

Tags: time-series, distributions, population, change-point, monitoring

I have a time series data of populations, e.g. for each time point, I have the blood pressure of 1 million of rats. How can I monitor that the distribution of this population drift over time?

For instance, if it is normal distribution, then the mean and variance might drift over time. But I do not know the distribution of my data, is there any nonparametric method to detect distribution drift over time?

Another example will be the world-wide income distribution, and I have 100 years of data. How to measure the distribution changing year over year?

Thanks.

Comment: Some basic statistics will still work, like max, min, mean, median, and quantile.

Comment: Any test models available for this kind of test? I can only find change detection models on data streams where each data point is just numerical or vector.

Comment: Look into control charts (quality control charts). They are used to detect changes when a signal is subject to drift